# Clearing input field on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The thing is pretty simple and clear that I want to clear my input field when I submit the field.

**State:**

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
   linkName: "",
   link: ""
});
```

**`handleSubmit` function:**

```
   Axios.post("/api/social", body, config)
      .then(
          setSocialList(prev => [
               ...prev,
               { _id: Math.random(), link, linkName }
          ])
      )
      .then(setFormData({ link: " ", linkName: " " }));
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

With this I am unable to clear my `formData` state, hence input field doesn't clears on submitting.

The full code: https://pastebin.com/5DCMLHPr

Answer (score 1):

You need two-way binding here. Pass `linkName` as value to your `input`.

```
<Input
    type="text"
    name="linkName"
    placeholder="Ex. Facebook"
    onChange={e => onChange(e)}
    value={linkName}
/>
```

Also, as suggested by *@norbitrial*, you need to pass a callback to your last `.then()` call, like this:

```
.then(() => { setFormData({ link: "", linkName: "" } }));
```

*Note:* that I have removed single character white spaces from the above reassignments.

Do it the same way in your other `input`, as well.

Comment: It worked :). But I see that it works just fine without passing any callback.

Comment: @RohitMishra I'm glad, it worked! Feel free to accept the answer. I am used to passing callbacks to `.then()` call, but maybe someone else can put more light on this, why it worked without a callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :), yeah I also mostly use callbacks when making async request, but don't know how it worked here without it.

Comment: @AkshitMehra We don't need arrow function here. Arrow bind the value of `this`.
`setFormData` is independent from the usecase here.
//CC @RohitMishra

Comment: @Ayushya But what difference will it make here? The question is whether to use a callback or not.

Comment: @AkshitMehra This slightly impacts performance. Why would you unnecessarily use arrow function and introduce `this` object binding when you dont need it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the values of link and linkName with input fields, otherwise the value is updated in the state but the input will still have the values which is entered and it wouldn't reflect any programmatically updated value.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";
import Axios from "axios";
import { SocialContext } from "./SocialContext";

const SocialForm = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        linkName: "",
        link: ""
    });
    const [socialList, setSocialList] = useContext(SocialContext);
    const { linkName, link } = formData;
    const onChange = e =>
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const socialList = {
            linkName,
            link
        };
        try {
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "x-auth-token": `${token}`
                }
            };
            const body = JSON.stringify(socialList);
            Axios.post("/api/social", body, config)
                .then(
                    setSocialList(prev => [
                        ...prev,
                        { _id: Math.random(), link, linkName }
                    ])
                )
                .then(setFormData({ link: " ", linkName: " " }));
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    };
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <br />
            <Form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)} className="socialForm">
                <Row form>
                    <Col md={5}>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="LinkName">LinkName</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="text"
                                name="linkName"
                                value={linkName}
                                placeholder="Ex. Facebook"
                                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={5}>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="Link">Link</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="text"
                                name="link"
                                value={link}
                                placeholder="Ex. https://www.facebook.com/"
                                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Button>Add</Button>
            </Form>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default SocialForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is basically `setFormData` function is called immediately, so you are not passing a callback to `then` what you want to call **after** the `Axios` post finished.

Based on that you need to have:

```
.then(() => setFormData({ link: " ", linkName: " " }))
```

Instead of:

```
.then(setFormData({ link: " ", linkName: " " }))
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Can you think of any other way to work it around?